# Application not finding route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my view, I have the following (slim):

```
= link_to 'Delete', cancel_admin_ticket_path, data: { confirm: t('.confirm', default: t("helpers.links.confirm", default: 'Are you sure?')) }, class: 'btn btn-danger destroy-btn'
```

In my admin/tickets_controller.rb, I have:

```
def cancel
  @ticket = Ticket.find params[:id]
  existing_workflow_state = @ticket.workflow_state
  msg_success = "Ticket #{@ticket.number} status has been changed from  #{existing_workflow_state} to cancelled"
  msg_already_cancelled = "Ticket #{@ticket.number} is already cancelled"
  msg_failure = "Ticket #{@ticket.number} status is  #{@ticket.workflow_state}, it cannot be cancelled"
  if existing_workflow_state == 'cancelled'
    redirect_to admin_tickets_path, alert: "Ticket #{@ticket.number} has already been cancelled"
  elsif !ticket_can_be_deleted(@ticket).nil?
    @ticket.workflow_state = 'cancelled'
    @ticket.save
    redirect_to admin_tickets_path, notice: "Ticket #{@ticket.number} status has been changed from  #{existing_workflow_state} to cancelled"
  else
    redirect_to admin_tickets_path, alert: "Ticket #{@ticket.number} status is  #{existing_workflow_state}, it cannot be cancelled"
  end
end
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :tickets, except: [:edit] do
    member do
      put 'cancel', to: 'tickets#cancel'
    end
  end
end
```

When I do rake routes, here's the route I get:

```
cancel_admin_ticket PUT  /admin/tickets/:id/cancel(.:format) admin/tickets#cancel
```

When I try running the app, I get the following error message:

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"admin/tickets"}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add `method: :put` to the `link_to` method and the `@ticket` as an argument for the named route: `cancel_admin_ticket_path(@ticket)`